# BootstrapSwitchDirective is not working with ngModel in Angular4

Tags: angular, angular-directive, bootstrap-switch

I'm trying to implement BootstrapSwitch library into my Angular 4 project. I created the below directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[switch]' })
export class SwitchDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() onText: string;
    @Input() offText: string;
    @Input() labelText: string;

    directive: any;

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.directive = $(el.nativeElement);

        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.onColor = 'success';
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var options = {
            onText: this.onText,
            offText: this.offText,
            labelText: this.labelText,
        };

        this.directive.bootstrapSwitch(options);

        this.directive.on('switch-change', function () {
            this.directive.bootstrapSwitch('toggleRadioState');
        });

        this.directive.on('switch-change', function () {
            this.directive.bootstrapSwitch('toggleRadioStateAllowUncheck');
        });

        this.directive.on('switch-change', function () {
            this.directive.bootstrapSwitch('toggleRadioStateAllowUncheck', false);
        });

    }
}
```

My input structure is:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" onText="Y" offText="N" labelText="Switch 1" switch #switch1>
<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" onText="Y" offText="N" labelText="Switch 2" switch #switch2>
```

I can use it with form submit as below:

```
<button (click)="submit(switch1.checked, switch2.checked)">Submit</button>
```

However, when I try to bind with ngModel, it is not working.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" onText="Y" offText="N" labelText="Switch 1" switch [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.switch1" name="switch1" [checked]="selectedItem.switch1== 1">
<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" onText="Y" offText="N" labelText="Switch 2" switch [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.switch2" name="switch2" [checked]="selectedItem.switch2 == 1">
```

What missing is I guess a similar approach as below in angularjs:

```
element.on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    if (ngModel) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(state);
        });
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding an `EventEmitter` into my `SwitchDirective`.

In the directive, I have added:

```
@Output() switch = new EventEmitter<any>();

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.directive.on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state){
        if(fnc.observers.length)
            fnc.emit(state);
    });
}
```

Updated my input structure:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" onText="Y" offText="N" labelText="Switch 1" (switch)="updateModel(model, $event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.switch1" name="switch1" [checked]="selectedItem.switch1== 1">
```

Added related function to my component:

```
updateModel(model: Model, state: boolean){
    model.attribute = state;
}
```